# how to get friends profile image in friend list of facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am creating a iPhone app in which i have to show friend list with their images.
I am using Facebook graph api. i am getting the friends id and name but not the images.
So please suggest me how i can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a FQL to get list of facebook friends & their Pics

```
 NSString *query = @"SELECT uid,name,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (";
query = [query stringByAppendingFormat:@"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %@)",userid];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"query",
                                nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate:self];
```

you will get a array in u r

```
  -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

Sample
      {
        "first_name" =User;
        "last_name" = R;
        name = "User R";
        "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/.jpg";
        uid = 595sd1;
         }
     {},{} etc

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for ur help ,, but how to do this with Facebook graph api. Facebook graph api does not have FBrequest class so how and where call this FQL?

Comment: @Anju : you are using old SDK i think , you this new one : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk